# Check whehter values are filled in in several ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to check whether a certain range is empty. Therefore I wrote the following code

```
Sub end_calculation1()

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D22:D27")) < 6 Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range D22:D27"
    End If

End Sub
```

This works but actually I would like to check two ranges. So not only D22:D27 but also D29:D30.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Comment: Have you considered just adding a second `IF` statement for the second range, since it's working as is?

Comment: WorksheetFunction.counta(range("d2:d27"),range("d29:d30"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add more `IF` statements if there aren't too many ranges you want to check:

```
Public Sub end_calculation1()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D22:D27")) < 6 Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range D22:D27"
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E22:E27")) < 6 Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range E22:E27"
    End If
End Sub
```

For multiple ranges, you can use a procedure to loop through the ranges and call a function to check each range:

```
Public Sub end_calculation_update()
    Dim rngs As Variant, i As Byte

    rngs = Array("D22:D27", "E22:E27", "F22:F27")
    For i = 0 To UBound(rngs)
        If (emptyRange(CStr(rngs(i)))) Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range " & rngs(i)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
Private Function emptyRange(rngAddress As String) As Boolean
    emptyRange = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(rngAddress)) < 6
End Function
```

**UPDATE in response to comments**
You could check all the ranges in a single line:

```
Public Sub end_calculation_revised()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D22:D27,D29:E30")

    If (WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) < rng.Cells.Count) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range " & rng.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would add <rngAddress.cells.count rather than fixed 6 as the 2nd range is 2 cells

Answer (score 1):

Is the cell D28 always full, or always empty?

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D22:D30")) < 9 Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range D22:D27 and D:28:D30"
End If
```

If you don't want to include cell D28 in the detection then just have another If statement after the first one.

```
    Sub end_calculation1()

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D22:D27")) < 6 Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range D22:D27"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D28:D30")) < 6 Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the answers in range D28:D30"
        End If
    End Sub
```

The Exit Sub is in there to stop the user getting 2 error messages.

If you want to go a stage further you could maintain an "error string" where you add the error messages to a string and detect if the string is empty at the end of the If statements.  This way you could trap all the errors in one go and present the user with a list of cells that haven't been completed.